# How to retrieve $_POST field names

Tags: php, post

I have a page that has 4 different forms on it all submitted via post (submitted at different times), with the purpose of inserting information into a database. The forms all have

```
name="table_name[field_name]"
```

And I want to build one INSERT query for all the forms. Something like this:

```
    if (isset($_POST) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO *get table name* SET *get field name* = $_POST["table name"]["field name"],
etc;
    }
```

Comment: Use a hidden field in each individual form that serves as an ID, change the $tablename variable for the SQL. For security reasons, do not do it straight into the string. Use a switch statements to hard-code the table name.

Comment: @Zach Smith actually what do you mean by this `INSERT INTO *get table name* SET *get field name* = $_POST["table name"]["field name"]` query

Comment: There will be a $_POST array that looks something like this ["table_name" => ["field 1" => name, "field 2" => name, etc.]]. (i think?). I then want to build a single sql statement that uses the keys to define the table parameters in the table, and the values as the values

Comment: But I guess cycling through the assoc. array and creating and array of keys may be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create hidden fields in each form named for example `form1` and `form2` etc.
and build your query like this

You have these two forms for example

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form1">
    <input type="text" name="some_field">
    <input type="text" name="other_field">
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>

<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form2">
    <input type="text" name="field">
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

you can build the INSERT query using this method (you can improve it)

```
<?php

$tables = array('form1' => 'table_name','form2' => 'table_name2');

// Building INSERT QUERY
$sql = "INSERT INTO ";

// keep only wanted fields (change this) to 'field' => value
$data = $_POST;

$count = 0;
$i = 0;

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $tables)){
        $sql .= $tables[$key] . ' SET ';
        unset($data[$key]);
        $count = count($data);

    } else { 
        if($count !== 0){
           $i++;
           $sql .= " $key = '$value' ";
           $sql .= $i == $count ? " " : " AND ";
        }

    }
}

echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $field)
{
    echo $_POST[$field];
}
```

`$field` contains the your html form fields.